# Entity Framework, Multi Threading, and Transactions

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, transactions

I have an application that reads data from one database, and transforms that data into a new form and writes it into a new database. Some of the tables in the new database are made from multiple tables in the old database so there is a large amount of reading and writing going on. Here is the basic concept of the system:

```
public void TransferData()
{
    OldEntities oldContext = new OldEntities()
    NewEntities newContext = new NewEntities()
    using(var transaction = newContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try{
            TransferTable(oldContext, newContext);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}

public void TransferTable(OldEntities oldContext, NewEntities newContext)
{
    List<Entity1> mainTable = oldContext.Where();
    Parallel.ForEach(mainTable, (row) =>
        {
            using(NewEntities anotherNewContext = new NewContext())
            {
                anotherNewContext.Database.UseTransaction(newContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction);
                // Do Work
            }
        });
}
```

This causes the following exception:

> The transaction passed in is not associated with the current connection. Only transactions associated with the current connection may be used.

How can I get around this. The transaction will always be coming from a different EF context but I need them all to share the same transaction. I couldn't find a way to create the new context as a "child" of the original and I am trying to avoid creating a transaction entirely separate from the EF context. Any suggestions?

Comment: "I am trying to avoid creating a transaction entirely separate from the EF context" - Why?

Comment: @user469104 Probably mostly out of naivety. I am admittedly weak with transactions and it is added because I couldn't allow partial loads. I assume that creating a transaction outside of the EF context would require some kind of special handling. If I'm wrong on this, then please do, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent overview of transactions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx) which explains how to use transactions in a variety of contexts some of which are similar to yours. Rather than trying to fix your code *as is* it may be that a modified approach will help.

I assume you are using EF6

Comment: Whoa! An MSDN page with useful information! That's a collector's item.